# Hyperlink connect to image file in php page

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, tags

I am writing following code

```
<?php 

  if ($reminderplus>0)
  {
      echo '<image source="/filepath/thisimage" width="100" height="50">'.'<center><b> Reminder Center</b></center>' ;
  }


?>
```

i want to add the link to that image , so if user clicks it that takes to another page, 
usually i add `< a href :thisfile.php  </a>` but here i am little confused where it need to add.

please can somebody help me and tell me where it need to be placed ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
echo '<a href="path_to_page"><img src="/filepath/thisimage" width="100" height="50">'.'<center><b> Reminder Center</b></center></a>' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly you have to put your link before your image, and you also can repeat your link in your centered text like below.

```
echo '<a href="page_name.php"><image source="/filepath/thisimage" width="100" height="50"></a>'.'<center><b><a href="page_name.php">Reminder Center</a></b></center>' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
if ($reminderplus>0)
  {
echo '<a href="http://google.com"> <img src="smartphones.png" width="100" height="50">'.'<center><b> Reminder Center</b></center></a>' ;
}
?>
```

This works perfectly check it .

Answer (score 0):

First off, in valid HTML this should be:

```
echo '<image src="/filepath/thisimage" width="100" height="50">'.'<center><b> Reminder Center</b></center>' ;
```

And the link should be

```
<a href="thisfile.php"></a>
```

Then, for the link, if you want it to be linking just the image then put it around the image code, like so

```
echo '<a href="thisfile.php"><image src="/filepath/thisimage" width="100" height="50"></a>'.'<center><b> Reminder Center</b></center>' ;
```

Otherwise, if you wanted both the text and the image to be a link, just put it around both of them.

```
echo '<a href="thisfile.php"><image src="/filepath/thisimage" width="100" height="50"></a>'.'<a href="thisfile.php"><center><b> Reminder Center</b></center></a>' ;
```

HTML's quite flexible in that it doesn't really care what you put first, as long as you open and close it in the same order.